# German abbreviations for instrument names in score markings (Deutsche Armeemärsche)

Tags: orchestra, orchestration

I'd like to know to which instruments are these signatures referring.

[image: score with German instrument abbreviations]

And these parts:

[image: as above, with "Fl./Ob./Es-+B-Kl. 8va+16va" circled, instrument numbers also circled]

Additionally, I'd like to how to use this score music. This book is titled as "Particell". Does it mean that multiple instruments can share the same score? What about the last three instruments? How come there are two scores for three instruments "Posaunen", "Bässe" and "Schlagzeug"? Is something missing here?

[image: as above, with "Holzbläser ...", "Spielm.-Pf. in Ces", "Spielm.-Tr.", and "Hörner" circled]

Answer (score 9):

This is a [*condensed score*](https://silverclefmusic.com/about-scores-for-band/) [related to a [reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_(music))] of a full score for band: information is condensed on a limited number of staffs, instead of having one staff per instrument, which could make it easier to have an overview while reading/analyzing.

The indication +8va and +16va [though usually notated as +15ma] means that these notes are doubled at the octave/two octaves by the indicated instruments.

2 Kl. Fl. would mean 2 parts for piccolo and 4 Trp. 4 parts for trumpet.

Based on the only information provided, one would assume there are 3 horns (first staff), 3 trombones (second staff) and one part for "bass instruments" (also on second staff).

Abbreviations:

Fl./Ob./Es-+B-Kl.: flute/oboe/Eb and Bb clarinet

Holzbläser: woodwinds

Kl. Fl.: piccolo

Sopr.-K.: [soprano cornet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soprano_cornet)

Sax./Trp.: saxophone/trumpet

Ten.-Hr./Bar.: tenor horn/baritone

Spielm.-Pf. : [Spielmannspfeifen (fifes)](https://www.spielmannszug-oberviechtach.de/der-verein/instrumente/)

Spielm.-Tr. : Spielmannstrommeln (marching snare drums)

Hörner: horns

Posaunen: trombones

Bässe: bass instruments (bass tuba and double bass)

Schlagzeug: percussion

Comment: "Sax." more likely means "Saxhorn" (Flügelhorn).

Comment: @PiedPiper The term *Saxhorn* is very infrequently used in German, compared to *Flügelhorn* I would assume the relation as lower than 1:20, so I'm not convinced in that respect.

Comment: It's interesting that the Spielmannspfeifen part is the only part that is transposed, and in C-flat!

Comment: @guidot I agree the term *Saxhorn* would be unusual, but in that kind of band you would be much more likely to find flügelhorns than saxophones.

Comment: On p. 2 of [this score](https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/download.blasmusik-shop.de/daten/Partituren-MP3/DeutscheArmeemaerscheBand2.pdf), you see both saxophones and cornets.

Comment: @Karlo OK, the book seems to be of arrangements from 1970, so saxophones *are* intended. You can ignore my first comment.

Comment: The piccolo abbreviation is probably Kleine Flote.

Comment: Also interesting example of half time in the time signature. It is not 4/4 but 2/2. Dont see examples of that in the wild every day.

Comment: @NeilMeyer Cut common time (=2/2) is probably more common than 2/4 (or 6/8) for a march. 4/4 would be very unusual and arguably incorrect. For a classic example of a 2/2 march see Sousa's "The Stars and Stripes Forever".

Comment: @NeilMeyer Yes, Kleine Flöte.

Comment: @Karlo Do you know how to use this old-style condensed scores? These are not chords rights? How do I know which group of notes belongs to an instrument?

Comment: @Getleft "How to use a condensed score" would make a good *separate* question. And it should probably be edited out of *this* question (which is about translating German abbreviations).